# Slow wifi with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, realtek, realtek-wireless

I am trying to figure out the next steps with troubleshooting my wifi connection. I am running Ubuntu on an ancient Dell 7110N. The wifi seemed fine up until recently but now I am lucky to get 1 Mbps. I just put in a Netgear D7000 router and all of our other devices are purring (network manager says that my signal is at 90%). Things that I have tried:

- Restarting with an older kernel
- Disabling 802.11n (subsequently re-enabled)
- Changing the channel of the router
- Disabling ipv6 (subsequently re-enabled)
- Changing ant_sel, though I can't recall how I did that and cannot be sure that the change took effect.
- Installing the rtlwifi_new driver off of github and then removing it because I couldn't get connected to wifi at all.

I have been doing some more googling on this issue and suspect that my wireless card/chipset may not be supported. Can anyone confirm that this is correct and if there is a fix? I have spent days on this problem, my child hardly recognises me anymore, and I am not sure if I should just throw in the towel and get a wireless USB.

UPDATE: I finally reached my fristration threshold and just reinstalled the OS. I wish that I knew what caused the problem to begin with, but I am now humming along at a 70 Mbps so I will cross my fingers and just hope that it doesn't happen again.

```
 lyn@lyn-Dell-System-Inspiron-N7110:~$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 34
       serial: 4c:80:93:62:ec:5b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.0.0-37-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.0.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:32 memory:d0600000-d0601fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 05
       serial: 14:fe:b5:9d:97:d6
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 multicast=yes
       resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0404000-d0404fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
lyn@lyn-Dell-System-Inspiron-N7110:~$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Memory at d0705000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Dell 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at d070a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34
    Memory at d0700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: d0600000-d06fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: d0500000-d05fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d0400000-00000000d04fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Dell 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 23
    Memory at d0709000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Mobile SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Dell 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Mobile SATA AHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    I/O ports at 3088 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 3094 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 3080 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 3090 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 3060 [size=32]
    Memory at d0708000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
    Memory at d0704000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 BGN
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    Memory at d0600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

02:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Dell uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 18
    Memory at d0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Memory at d0404000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at d0400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```